# Calculating the standard error for a ratio estimator in a stratified sample

Tags: estimation, standard-error, survey-sampling

I need to use Lohr's ([2d Ed](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9780429296284/sampling-sharon-lohr)) method of calculating a standard error for an estimate generated from a ratio estimator based on a stratified sample. In working out her example on page 145-146, I find that the fraction in her example is calculated opposite to how she shows it in her MSE equations on page 144. Specifically, on p144, the fraction has the estimated $x$ as numerator, and the population $x$ in the denominator. but in her example she reverses them. Neither method produces her example result. I'm trying to figure out which version is correct. I would appreciate some help. (The Cochran method uses a sampling fraction in place of the fraction of pop and sample $x$'s).